# Slim application not updating immediately after saving

Tags: php, slim

I am trying out Slim 4 (I've previously used Slim 3 but many things seem to have changed in the new versions of Slim and Twig) and I have a very simple starter application:

```
<?php

use DI\Container;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\TwigMiddleware;
use Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware;


// Autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


// Create Container using PHP-DI
$container = new Container();
AppFactory::setContainer($container);


// Create the app
$app = AppFactory::create();


// Show meaningful errors with ErrorMiddleware
$errorMiddleware = new ErrorMiddleware(
$app->getCallableResolver(),
$app->getResponseFactory(),
true,
false,
false
);

$app->add($errorMiddleware);


// Set view in Container
$container->set('view', function() {
return Twig::create('views', [
    'auto_reload' => true,
    'cache' => false
]);
});

$app->add(TwigMiddleware::createFromContainer($app));


// Define routes
$app->get('/', function($req, $res) {
return $this->get('view')->render($res, 'home.twig');
});

$app->get('/heroes', function($req, $res) {
$users = [
    'Batman',
    'Supes',
    'Flash'
];

return $this->get('view')->render($res, 'heroes.twig', [
    'users' => $users
]);
});


// Run the app
$app->run();
```

After several tests I have noticed that if I make a change, for example if I type a different twig file or if I write a different route, changes are not reflected when I refresh the browser. No matter how many times I hit refresh, changes are not reflected until approx. a minute later.

I'm using MAMP PRO v6.6. The project is built with the following dependencies:

```
{
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^4.10",
    "slim/psr7": "^1.5",
    "php-di/php-di": "^6.4",
    "slim/twig-view": "^3.3"
}
}
```

I have added auto-reload and cache settings to the Twig creation but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going into the php.ini file and commenting out the OPCache block towards the end of the file. That took care of it.